# Why does my DB project's .dbmdl file change even when I make no changes to the project?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I'm running into a small but weird annoyance that seems to be happening to other people, too (for example, [check out the revision history of SEDE](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=06d2c92a8210eed642c8d1cc6820996ad7eef8f4)). I have a SQL Server 2008 database project in Visual Studio 2010 that works properly. When I go to commit/checkin to source control, I'm told that my DB project's **`.dbmdl` file has changed**, even when I've made no changes to the project!

I'm not sure if the changes are triggered by building my solution (which also includes an ASP.NET MVC application and a unit test project) or by simply opening the DB project, but this is getting kind of annoying and is creating clutter in source control.

**Is it possible to stop these changes from occurring, or get rid of the `.dbmdl` file whatsoever?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the function of the DBMDL File in VS database project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634649/what-is-the-function-of-the-dbmdl-file-in-vs-database-project)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe Visual Studio serializes the dbmdl file every time the project is opened. The only possible work around would be to keep the project open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I were to change the project's contents, would those changes be reflected inside the `.dbmdl` file? I'm considering just ignoring the file in version control - will the project function properly with an out-of-date `.dbmdl`?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I'd be reluctant to risk using an out-of-date file.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634649/what-is-the-function-of-the-dbmdl-file-in-vs-database-project/3766902#3766902 , your dbmdl file should not be checked into the repo, and will never be out of date.

Comment: some info about dbmdl file is here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bahill/archive/2009/02/24/deserialization-has-failed-for-project.aspx

Answer (score 19):

If you delete the .dbml file, it is rebuilt without errors or warnings, so I think it's just a cache file for references, intellisense, etc. I'm going to exclude it from source control.

Answer (score 4):

See related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634649/what-is-the-function-of-the-dbmdl-file-in-vs-database-project).  The .dbmdl file is unique per user (and some kind of cache, as said above) and so the right solution is indeed to exclude it from source control.