# What is the function of the DBMDL File in VS database project

Tags: visual-studio, database-project, visual-studio-dbpro

What is the function of the DBMDL file in a visual studio database project?

Answer (score 435, accepted):

From what I can make out, it is a serialized file of your db model and is used as a cache for improving the performance of deployment. It is unique per user thus should not be checked into source control.

Comment: When creating a new SQL 2008 Database Project VisualSVN automatically elects not to check this file in so that also suggests to me that it's not a good idea to check it in to source control.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I remove these dbmdl files, opening the solution results in a "contains a reference to a project which does not exist" error from database project to server project that doesn't show up again on subsequent loads.

Comment: That's because the dbmdl file contains the reference, and deleting it causes the error message. The file is then re-generated by Visual Studio and the error goes away.

Comment: Wish I could add another +1 for the source control comment even though it was not even asked.

Comment: When I first created a "SQL Server Database" project in Visual Studio 2017, it automatically created a `<project name>.dbmdl` file.  But at some point after I added some tables and built the project, the `<project name>.dbmdl` file disappeared.  I seem to be able to carry on without it.  Good to know it is not something to submit to source control.

Comment: If your next question is to check what is the JFM file, is almost the same than DBML, started to appear after a specific Windows upgrade.