# Visual Studio DB project: model already has an element that has the same name

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am currently working on a build of a Solution with several Database Projects (Staging, Core, Business) in Visual Studio 2013. Unfortunately I get into troubles, when i have the same object in different projects.

```
Error:  SQL71508: The model already has an element that has the same name DIM.
```

As there are build dependencies, the first project will be able to CREATE the schema DIM. The second one will fail. Therefore a lot of errors will be thrown.

How am i able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was very confusing, but what finally solved my issue was:

1. saving & closing the solution
2. removing all *.dbmdl files (each project had one)
3. reopening the solution

Reopening took a while, but finally those errors were gone.
[Function of DBMDL files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634649/what-is-the-function-of-the-dbmdl-file-in-vs-database-project)